# Cannot make @font-face work on IE

Tags: css, font-face

I cannot make @font-face work on IE.
I was trying many ways suggested but nothing seems to work.

- I was generated my font here: [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)
- I added the mime type '.woff' for this website.

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fbahava_regularregular';
  src: url('http://2send.co.il/Content/Fonts/fbahava-regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('http://2send.co.il/Content/Fonts/fbahava-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('http://2send.co.il/Content/Fonts/fbahava-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('http://2send.co.il/Content/Fonts/fbahava-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('http://2send.co.il/Content/Fonts/fbahava-regular-webfont.svg#fbahava_regularregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.btn_submit {
    font-family: 'fbahava_regularregular' ,Arial;
    height: 56px;
    padding: 0px 35px;   
    background-image: url('../images/btn_pix.png');
    border: 0 solid white;
    font-size: 48px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #BE331B inset, 1px 0 0 #A42A15 inset, -1px 0 0 #A42A15 inset, 0 -1px 0 #8C200E inset, 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 0 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #BE331B inset, 1px 0 0 #A42A15 inset, -1px 0 0 #A42A15 inset, 0 -1px 0 #8C200E inset, 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 0 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #BE331B inset, 1px 0 0 #A42A15 inset, -1px 0 0 #A42A15 inset, 0 -1px 0 #8C200E inset, 0 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 0 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I am stuck, any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Try putting single quotes around 'fbahava_regularregular' in your font-family declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should single quote you're reference:

```
.btn_submit{
    font-family: 'fbahava_regularregular' ,Arial; 
}
```